# Excel - Deleting a row does not automatically insert a blank row

Tags: excel, excel-2010

As seen in the photos, I have a particular sheet in my workbook that refuses to add a blank row to the bottom of the worksheet after a row is deleted.  Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here is a screenshot of a the bottom of a typical sheet in my workbook before I delete a row
[image: Here is a screenshot of a the bottom of a typical sheet in my workbook before I delete a row]

After I delete a row on the good sheet, another row is automatically inserted on the bottom
[image: After I delete a row on the good sheet, another row is automatically inserted on the bottom]

Now here is the bottom of the problem sheet before I delete a row
[image: Now here is the bottom of the problem sheet before I delete a row]

After I delete the row on the problem sheet, a new row is not being automatically added to the sheet
[image: After I delete the row on the problem sheet, a new row is not being automatically added to the sheet]

Comment: And you're in Excel 2010?

Comment: I cannot regenerate your problem in Excel 2016. Is there any macro in the worksheet?

Comment: Is its height set to 0? Can you reference it using VBA? Or type an address on that row in the address box?

Comment: @BigBen Excel 2016

Comment: I can't repro in Excel 2016 either

Comment: @TerryW the only macro on the sheet is a button that when clicked it runs ActiveSheet.CheckSpelling, but that button exists on every sheet in the workbook

Comment: In the Immediate Window, type `Rows(Rows.Count).Hidden = False` and press Enter. Do you still not have that row?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it looks like you're right, the new rows are being automatically set to 0 for some reason.  Unfortunately I can't seem to stop it from happening and I still don't know why it's happening

Comment: @BigBen it is not revealing the bottom rows, but strangely enough, it's also not revealing rows i hid when testing that line of code.

Comment: Well I think you've found the problem with the height though.

Answer (score 0):

Rows cannot be added or destroyed. An Excel sheet has a static number of rows and columns at all times. This limit depends on the version of the workbook housing the worksheet. Rows an columns can be hidden but they are never truly gone.

Complete details about the limitations of Excel can be found here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3